# Optimal way to define collections with similar structure in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database-normalization, denormalization

I am trying to create a forum like section, for which I use MongoDB to store data.

So my structure consist of main thread and posts.

for example user creates a thread with

```
{
  title: String
  post: Post // initial post
  totalReactionCounts: { [key: emojiName]: number } // store all post reactions number for easy sort
}
```

and other users can post some comments under the thread

```
{
 text: String,
 reactions: { enum: [...emojis] } 
 repliedTo: Post // users can reply to others comments
 thread: Thread,
 isMain: Boolean  // whether this is initial post of thread
}
```

I think this is fairly simple schema, to have main thread which stores only title and multiple posts i.e. `one-to-many`.
What I cast doubt is, whether I should have `isMain` flag, that indicates whether this is initial post by author.

The reason I store this kind of flag, is that other participants can put a reaction on both thread and child posts. However, this way of "normalization" costs me difficulties when I do search for thread `title` and main posts `text`.

Another denormalized approach would suggest to store `reactions` and `text` directly in `Thread`. However this way I would have repeated code, although they belongs to different models.

My question, how to handle this kind of proble, where collections share similar data and have a relation between them, without losing performance gains provided by MongoDB in case of denormalized approach.

Comment: This question comes up quite often. With MongoDB you should aim for de-normalized structure - this is the advantage you can use. Before deciding how you design (normalized or denormalized form), you should know clearly the important operations (queries) and how they work and perform. And, the amount of data and the relationships. These can clarify your design.

Comment: Hi @prasad_, thanks for reply. Thus, when  it comes to MongoDB and especially to denormalization, DYI sometimes doesn't work, thought in sane boundaries. Am I right?

Comment: I can only suggest write couple of queries and see what it feels like.